# Which database is most easy to use with C language?

Tags: c, database, file-handling

I have a project to be made on "college counseling and admission" in C language and I'm confused whether to choose a database or the file management system in C for the data.
As I have no prior knowledge of connecting C with any of the databases around and also because I find the file handling in C some what difficult.

What would you recommend?

Comment: Horribly subjective...Consider SQLite.  All the major DBMS provide ODBC connectivity; that is usable (not necessarily very easy, but pretty functional).

Comment: Agreed. I didn't recommend it because of the easy part. Considering some body having trouble with file handling in c, building sqlite amalgamation or library along would be difficult to grasp. Also this assumes that he does not require an external interface changing the database since sqlite will be local.

Answer (score 2):

MYSQL has a pretty good and easy interface to be used with c.

You can write basic operations in 30-40 lines of c code.

File handling will not scale and would be difficult once you change your file structure and info. With a database you can keep changing your info logically by adding new tables and still reuse most of the code by just adding new table names.

[mysql tutorial c in linux environment](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/mysqlcapitutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a .plist file and implement it into a UITableView using the .h and .m files. That is the easiest, most simple way to do it. You can keep adding rows to your plist file without having to also code the changes too!

Let me know if you have a better idea!

Comment: The question is about C, not Objective-C.

Comment: You might need to be quite a bit more specific about the environment in which those various files exist.